# Android Wi-Fi hotspot DNS resolver: locally point domain name to custom address without root

Tags: wifi-hotspot, dns

So, I know dnsmasq is used as DNS/DHCP server in Android when running as a Wi-Fi hotspot, that [dnsmasq can be used to point users to a specific address when resolving addresses](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/dnsmasq#Override_addresses), and that there is a way to set a custom system-wide DNS server, either by setting it in the phone, or [by using the Cloudflare 1.1.1.1 app](https://blog.cloudflare.com/enable-private-dns-with-1-1-1-1-on-android-9-pie/).

Is it possible to give custom DNS records to clients in an Android Wi-Fi hotspot, locally, without rooting the phone? Say, by modifying the "address" configuration parameter in dnsmasq somehow, by running a local DNS server in an unprivileged port, and using that as the system DNS, or by using a custom VPN config (which, from what I've read, is the way the 1.1.1.1 app works)?

Comment: I don't think it's possible without root, whether it's to modify name servers of dnsmasq or to run some other local DNS server